# How to write timer that doing sth every second minute

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want my timer does sth every second minute. In my timer I used stopwatch and Timers. The code below. The problem is, it doesn't work as I wish. It stops after first 2 minutes but it ignores other periods of time ( other two minuies loops ) Here what I tried To use. I just want to perform sth every second minut it stops then I manually start it again

```
   1 st
```

````
                MainTimer.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                double counter = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                if ((int)counter == 120 )
                {
                    // do sth
                    counter = 0;
                }
```    2 nd
````

```
            MainTimer.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            double counter = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            if ((int)counter % 120 == 0 )
            {
                // do sth
            }
```

```
The code
```

```
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

         public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainFunctionTimer();
            DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn = true;
        }
        bool Value = false;
        string Time = "00:00:00";
```

```
       private void MainFunctionTimer()
       {
          MainTimer.Text = Time;
          stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
          timer.Interval = 500;
          timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
      }

       private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
         Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            MainTimer.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            double counter = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            
            if ((int)counter == 120 )
            {
                // do sth
                counter = 0;
            }
        });
```

````
         private void Start_Stop_Butt_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Value == false)
            {
                Value = true;
                stopwatch.Start();
                timer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Value = false;
                stopwatch.Stop();
                timer.Stop();
            }
```     }

        private void Reset_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            MainTimer.Text = Time;
        }
````

```
 

Someone knows the way how to rewrite sth that it works correctly
```

Comment: If you want something to happen every 2 minutes, why not use a timer set to two minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have done most of the work. I just modify some of the code and it works every two minutes. Try the following code.

```
private void MainFunctionTimer()
{
    MainTimer.Text = Time;
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Interval = 1000;   // change here ,set it to 1000
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
 }
```

In the OnTimeElapsed event handler:

```
private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        MainTimer.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            
        double counter = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

        if (((int)counter % 120 == 0 && (int)counter != 0))
        {
            //here make a stop every 120 seconds
            Value = false;
            timer.Stop();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            counter = 0;
            // do sth

            Console.WriteLine("TIMER Close==============");
                                  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also some changes in Reset Button:

```
private void Reset_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    stopwatch.Reset();
    Value = false;
    MainTimer.Text = Time;
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: That what you wrote it works also for me, but if I want to launch other method every 110 seconds (10 seconds before finish) it cuts 10 seconds every loop. I wrote other conditional statement but every loop the method launches 10 seconds too early for example first loop 1:50 correct second loop 1:40 incorrect third loop 1:30 incorrect......... But time stops correct every 2 minutes

Comment: I posted question if you would like to help me this time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74560683/how-to-prevent-my-method-launches-every-loop-10-seconds-earlier

Comment: Of course, with pleasure.